# svn, ssh: Connection refused most of the time; other computers can connect

Tags: networking, server, ssh, svn

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.3 and svn as well as ssh (to servers) only works sometimes in a short time window after booting my computer, but most of the time I get "Connection refused". The problem only started some weeks ago, before it, everything worked perfectly fine.

It should not be a server issue and also not a router issue, since using my notebook I can connect without problems.

I have already reinstalled Ubuntu and tried 12.10 and 13.04, the problem happens also in these versions. However, after reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04.3, it seemed to work, I may re-introduced the problem by copying back my home folder from the previous installation (if there is some config in this folder?).

Uncommenting "dnsmasq" in NetworkManager.conf seems to help in regard to the ssh problem, but for svn I still can get no connection.

```
   ssh -vvvvv
```

gives

```
   OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012  
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to xxxx port 22.
   debug1: connect to address xxx port 22: Connection refused
   ssh: connect to xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

What other output do you need?

Thank you for your help, the problem really drives me crazy.

Edit: Now ssh works and svn not and I did not change anything, before the last boot svn worked.

I tried

```
 arp-scan -I eth0 -l
```

and got a (DUP:2) with two times the same IP and MAC adress.

Comment: Are you sure openssh-server is installed and running on the other end?

Comment: Yes, since I can connect with my notebook without any problems to the svn server, as well as to the ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

You might be connecting from the network with port 22 closed. Try for example to connect from 3G network or some kind of.

Answer (score 0):

In burp:

*proxy -- options -- proxy listeners -- (table) -- interface*

by default it is loopback only, changed it (via the [edit] button on the left) to "all interfaces", and it began to work.